# Changing axis displays for a graph using plot3D in R?

Tags: r, plot, 3d

I'm hoping to keep in the image below the ticks on the vertical `z` axis, but remove ticks and numbers from the `x` and `y` axes. I would like to be able to label my `x` and `y` axes with a label for each condition in my matrix, but have not figured out how to do this with `text3D`. For some reason (because I'm on a mac?) I can't download `axes3D`, which is one potential solution I've seen in other responses.

Here is my code:

```
x = c(0,1)
y = c(0,1)
zval = c(104.1861, 108.529, 110.3675, 110.4112)
z = matrix (zval, nrow=2, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
hist3D(x,y,z, zlim=c(101,111), colvar = NULL, d=2, col = "lightblue", NAcol = "white", breaks = NULL, colkey = NULL, theta=-60, phi=20, nticks=10, axes=TRUE, ticktype="detailed", space=0.5, lighting=TRUE, light="diffuse", shade=.5, ltheta = 50, bty = "g")
```

My output
 [image: output]

Ultimately, I'd like something more along the lines of this:
[image]

I'm very new to R.

stackoverflow.com/questions/26794236/ggplot2-3d-bar-plot

^ this seems like it might be what I need, but I couldn't replicate the code without an error. When I tried to run this piece I got an error because my x and z (in this case) axes aren't numerical:

```
cloud(y~x+z, d, panel.3d.cloud=panel.3dbars, col.facet='grey', xbase=0.4, ybase=0.4, scales=list(arrows=FALSE, col=1), par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = "transparent")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might be helpful (with the caveat that 3D plots can sometimes make interpretation more challenging).

First, I recreated a data frame `d` based on something similar to what you started with:

```
x = c(0, 0, 1, 1)
y = c(0, 1, 0, 1)
z = c(104.1861, 108.529, 110.3675, 110.4112)

d <- data.frame(
  x = factor(as.logical(x)),
  y = factor(as.logical(y)),
  z = z
)
```

Note that for `x` and `y` I converted the 0 and 1 to `FALSE` and `TRUE` with `as.logical`, then made them factors.

Then for the plot:

```
library(latticeExtra)

cloud(z ~ x + y, data = d, panel.3d.cloud=panel.3dbars, col.facet='grey', 
      xbase=0.4, ybase=0.4, scales=list(arrows=FALSE, col=1), 
      par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = "transparent")))
```

You will want the formula as `z ~ x + y` where `z` is a numeric response.

**Edit**: If you wish to customize the axis labels, you can set the `factor` labels as follows (for example):

```
d <- data.frame(
  x = factor(as.logical(x), labels = c("Hi", "Lo")),
  y = factor(as.logical(y), labels = c("Label1", "Label2")),
  z = z
)
```

**Plot**

[image: 3D plot]

Comment: This is super helpful, thank you! Is there a way to do this with the x and y options labeled something other than true and false?

Comment: Great, glad to hear. You can give the labels whatever text you want. For example, you can do: `factor(as.logical(y), labels = c("Label1", "Label2"))`...I'll edit the answer with this information...

Comment: Basically, the `factor` level labels will dictate what text shows up in the axis labels.